# Dynamicaly Allocated Array in MIPS

Tags: mips, dynamic-memory-allocation

i need to create an array with user input.

```
creataArray:
    la  $a0, enterSize
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall

    li  $v0, 5
    syscall

    move    $s0, $v0    #Array Size
    add $s2, $s0, $zero #Backup size

    readElements:
        li $v0, 5   # syscall 5 reads array element (integer)
        syscall

        sw $v0, array($s1)  # save integer in $v0 to array $s1 to determine the next avaliable index

        addi    $s1, $s1, 4 #next index
        addi    $s0, $s0, -1    #size = size - 1

        bgt $s0, $zero, readElements


        add $v0, $s2, $zero     #array size return to main program
        la  $v1, array      #array adress return to main program
    jr  $ra
```

I can create an array with this code but i need to create an array with using dynamically allocated memory. How can i?

Comment: Memory allocation is operating system-dependent. What operating system are you using? My guess is you're using SPIM. System call 9 is the one that allocates memory.

Comment: SPIM & MARS both, syscall #9 allocates memory.  follow the inputs & outputs this syscall needs.